# Birth date or birth day?

Tags: word-choice

I have a question, is **birth date** or **birth day**?

I'm learning english and I have this question.

Comment: Either is acceptable, but "birth date" is more formal and only refers to the date on which someone was born. "Birthday" can also refer to the celebration that occurs on someone's birth date.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say or write, birth date. It's always date of birth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Birth *date*" is the exact date you were born (like December 31, 1999.)

"Birth*day*" is the same day each year (December 31).

You can talk about your "birth day", meaning the *actual* day of your birth, but this is not common.  More often I hear, "On the *day* I was *born* ..."

Answer (score 0):

We should call it birth date. it will be the accurate. Every year the same day of your birth day does not come, but the  date comes. For instance, suppose you were born on May 1st as a date and Monday is the day. So the next year on 1 st may the day Monday will not fall. So, we should call it BIRTH DATE.